# Disable *.example.com in Apache 2.2

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

My site works both with and without the www subdomain (i.e., both `example.com` and `www.example.com` work). However, `anything.example.com` also works and the same website content is served.

How can I disable all subdomains except `www.example.com`? I want all other subdomains to return a 404 error or just not show anything.

The config now is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to VirtualHost config and enabled mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|)domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

put

`ServerName www.domain.com`

and comment out #ServerAlias...

then when you request domain.com you will get to default apache site
apache2ctl -S will show you which one is default...

or if you want to do this via mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

This will give 403 for any request that's not designated for www.domain.com

Or if you want you can redirect them all to www so they don't use the other subdomain
options.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$  
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You forgot to say the most important thing: the default server for apache is the first file on apache/sites-enabled. Very smart move from Apache! I created a a-catch-all config file there and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a catch all vhost. Make sure it is the last vhost you define as anything not previously matched will be caught by it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      catchall
        ServerAlias *
        DocumentRoot /var/www/catchall
</VirtualHost>
```

To show nothing have a simple blank index.html file in the DocumentRoot of the vhost.

Comment: Thanks! Can I send 404 from catchall using apache config only?

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not a 404 as the resource has been found.

Comment: If you want to send a 404, DON'T create a catchall host and don't let your virtualhost match domains except the ones you want results for. Then apache will send the right errors about resources not being found. Don't try to make apache match something and then pretend it didn't!